# Rails is not finding vendor/assets in Rails 4.0.x in development mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I have the following setup:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

In `config/application.rb`:

```
 config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components')
```

In `vendor/assets/components/gridster/dist`:

```
jquery.gridster.min.css  jquery.gridster.with-extras.min.js
jquery.gridster.min.js
```

Yet, once I go to `http://localhost:3000/` and view source in the browser, these assets are not showing up...what do I have to do to get them there?

Update:

`application.js`:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate
//= require bootstrap
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
//= require jquery.gridster.min
//= require jquery.gridster.with-extras.min
//= require_tree .
```

`application.css.scss`:

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
 *= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap3
 *= require jquery.gridster.min
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

Comment: Can you post your `application.js` manifest? You may have forgotten to put them in there. You should be able to do something like `//= require_tree gridster`

Comment: Yes, I forgot to put it in application.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In application.js, add following lines

```
//= require gridster/dist/jquery.gridster.min
//= require gridster/dist/jquery.gridster.with-extras.min
```

In application.css, add following line

```
*= require gridster/dist/jquery.gridster.min
```

You need to add `reference` of the files so Sprockets will search the default asset locations i.e., `app/assets`, `lib/assets` and `vendor/assets` Plus any additional paths appended to `config.assets.paths`

Comment: Thanks Kirti, unfortunately, I get Sprockets::FileNotFound at....couldn't find file 'jquery.gridster.min' (see updated).  since I have config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'components') - will it find the files in vendor/assets/components/grid/dist/ ?

Comment: @Bruce see my updated answer. You need to provide the path till the js file as it is not directly present within components folder.

Comment: Thank you @Kirti - it worked! You don't also happen to know why I can't use the "\*" operator as in - //=require/gridster/dist/\* ?

Comment: I am not sure where exactly you want to use quotes. You can use quotes if the argument passed to require directive has spaces. Then you can surround the argument in spaces like //= require "my custom jquery" for a "my custom jquery.js" file

Comment: Miscommunication...I don't want to use quotes, I want to use an asterisk to signal to Sprockets to recursively find all the subdirectories and subsequent files under "dist" directory.

Comment: I think you might want to do require_tree /gridster/dist instead of require /gridster/dist/*